# Create a "Transaction Handler" smart contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

New to solidity and geth for my traineeship, I started deploying contrcts using the solidity online IDE and the geth dev mode. My problem is I tried a few different ways to do it but nothing seems to really work.

Code:

```
contract Transaction {
  address public owner;
  mapping (address => uint) public balances;

  function Transaction () {
      owner = msg.sender;
  }

  function validateTransaction (address receiver, uint amount) constant returns (bool) {
    if  (balances[owner] < amount || owner == receiver || amount == 0)
        return (false);
    balances[owner] -= msg.value;
    return (true);
  }

  function transact (address receiver, uint amount) {
    if (!validateTransaction(receiver, amount))
        return ;
    balances[receiver] += msg.value;
  }

  function remove () {
      if (msg.sender == owner)
        selfdestruct(owner);
  }
}
```

I also tried this contract of a solidity tutorial but it also don't work as I expected:

```
contract Coin {
    // The keyword "public" makes those variables
    // readable from outside.
    address public minter;
    mapping (address => uint) public balances;

    // Events allow light clients to react on
    // changes efficiently.
    event Sent(address from, address to, uint amount);

    // This is the constructor whose code is
    // run only when the contract is created.
    function Coin() {
        minter = msg.sender;
    }

    function mint(address receiver, uint amount) {
        if (msg.sender != minter) return;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
    }

    function send(address receiver, uint amount) {
        if (balances[msg.sender] < amount) return;
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
        Sent(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
    }
}
```

I am just trying to make a smart contract that can make transactions between the sender and a receiver but the accounts balances don't move. Are that functions only abstract to learn how solidity works or can this really make the balances change ? Thanks for your answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After have searched and work deeper on solidity I found that, indeed, this contract makes abstract transactions into HIS data. So the ether aren't truely sent and the balance variable is local to this contract.